# define simple and complext types with same name in XSD

Tags: xsd

I am stuck with an xsd definition problem. Please help to provide a solution -

I have two element structure possible -

```
<Books>
 <Book>Effective java</Book>
</Books>
```

OR

```
<Books>
 <Book>
    <Name>Effective java</Name>
    <Author>Josh</Author>
 </Book>
</Books>
```

I have tried using two different complex types to define each, but validation fails saying that we cannot have element with multiple types.
Also, I tried using union but looks like it can only work on inbuilt types.

Is this at all possible ? If yes, please help providing pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this solution which allows the mixing of Simple and complex types -

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name='Name' type='xs:string'/>
  <xs:element name='Author' type='xs:string'/>
  <xs:element name="Books">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name='Book' minOccurs='0'>
          <xs:complexType mixed='true'>
            <xs:all>
              <xs:element ref='Name' minOccurs='0'/>
              <xs:element ref='Author' minOccurs='0'/>
            </xs:all>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say that as such it is not possible because of schema's "unique particle attribution" and "element declarations consistent" constraints. Practically this means that in the same context you cannot have two elements with same name and different type. Allowing such would make the schema non-deterministic and that's why a plain old `<xs:choice>` won't work. All workarounds that come to my mind have side effects.

#### Possible workarounds

1) Rename the elements. For example, define the text-only book element as `<book-title>`. Then you can define different types for them and put them inside a `<xs:choice>`. The problem is of course the renaming.

2) Make child elements optional and allow `<book>` to have mixed content. This way you can have both text only or element only content. The problem is that text content will be allowed also when the child elements are present and this text can appear before, in between and after the child elements.

3) Declare the used type in the instance document. This can be done with `xsi:type="..."` attribute. Problems are that you need to specifically mention the used type in the instance document (with that extra attribute). Also in schema this is usually done by creating an abstract type and the referenced types are derived by restriction from that type. In your case only suitable superset type for `<book>` might be `xs:anyType` because mixed types cannot be derived from types that are not mixed.

4) Use some other structure definition language that does not require determinism. (RelaxNG might be suitable, although I'm not familiar with it.) The problem is of course the need to learn a new language and possible lack of software support.

Comment: Thanks jasso, I think the solution I finally used is (2) in your workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

I think your Book schema is a <choice> consisting of the simple text node and your type consisting of Name and Author. Look up <choice> in W3C's XSD spec.

Comment: `<choice>` can select one from different element names, not from different types. Having a choice between two elements with same name but different type is not possible because it requires validator to look past the current context.